# A lib for parsing lousy JSON - does it exist?

Tags: javascript, json

I need a library, that is capable of reading and parsing freely formed JSON, for example objects, that would be correct JavaScript object, for example a well-formed JSON is this:

```
{"hello": 1, "bye":2}
```

and I need a lib, that can read this:

```
{hello: 1, bye:2, }
```

It's perfectly correct in JavaScript and Haxe environments, isn't it? So why is there no parser that supports it? It's not a problem to write it myself, but first let's find out if it already exists.

Comment: Maybe [hjson](https://hjson.org/)?

Comment: What language do you need to access such a parser from? And no, the second example isn't valid JavaScript because it has a comma after the second property.

Comment: https://github.com/mbest/js-object-literal-parse

Comment: @JLRishe - trailing commas are valid in object literals as of ECMAScript 5, and the major browsers other than older IE have supported it for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HJSON, the Human JSON](https://hjson.org/) looks to be what you want. They can take some "malformed" JSON-esque syntax and output correct JSON.

```js
/*! @preserve
 * Hjson v2.0.0
 * http://hjson.org
 *
 * Copyright 2014-2016 Christian Zangl, MIT license
 * Details and documentation:
 * https://github.com/laktak/hjson-js
 *
 * This code is based on the the JSON version by Douglas Crockford:
 * https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (json_parse.js, json2.js)
 */
var Hjson=function(){"use strict";var r="\n",e=!1,n=function(r,e){function n(){return u=r.charAt(a),a++,u}var t,u,f="",o=0,i=!0,a=0;for(n(),"-"===u&&(f="-",n());u>="0"&&"9">=u;)i&&("0"==u?o++:i=!1),f+=u,n();if(i&&o--,"."===u)for(f+=".";n()&&u>="0"&&"9">=u;)f+=u;if("e"===u||"E"===u)for(f+=u,n(),("-"===u||"+"===u)&&(f+=u,n());u>="0"&&"9">=u;)f+=u,n();for(;u&&" ">=u;)n();return e&&(","===u||"}"===u||"]"===u||"#"===u||"/"===u&&("/"===r[a]||"*"===r[a]))&&(u=0),t=+f,u||o||!isFinite(t)?void 0:t},t=function(){function r(){u=0,f=" "}function e(r){return"{"===r||"}"===r||"["===r||"]"===r||","===r||":"===r}var t,u,f,o,i={'"':'"',"\\":"\\","/":"/",b:"\b",f:"\f",n:"\n",r:"\r",t:" "},a=function(r){var e,n=0,f=1;for(e=u-1;e>0&&"\n"!==t[e];e--,n++);for(;e>0;e--)"\n"===t[e]&&f++;throw new Error(r+" at line "+f+","+n+" >>>"+t.substr(u-n,20)+" ...")},c=function(r){return r&&r!==f&&a("Expected '"+r+"' instead of '"+f+"'"),f=t.charAt(u),u++,f},s=function(r){return t.charAt(u+r)},l=function(){var r,e,n,t="";if('"'===f)for(;c();){if('"'===f)return c(),t;if("\\"===f)if(c(),"u"===f){for(n=0,e=0;4>e&&(r=parseInt(c(),16),isFinite(r));e++)n=16*n+r;t+=String.fromCharCode(n)}else{if("string"!=typeof i[f])break;t+=i[f]}else t+=f}a("Bad string")},p=function(){for(var r="",e=0,n=0;;){var t=s(-n-5);if(!t||"\n"===t)break;n++}for(var u=function(){for(var r=n;f&&" ">=f&&"\n"!==f&&r-->0;)c()};f&&" ">=f&&"\n"!==f;)c();for("\n"===f&&(c(),u());;){if(f){if("'"===f){if(e++,c(),3===e)return"\n"===r.slice(-1)&&(r=r.slice(0,-1)),r;continue}for(;e>0;)r+="'",e--}else a("Bad multiline string");"\n"===f?(r+="\n",c(),u()):("\r"!==f&&(r+=f),c())}},h=function(){if('"'===f)return l();for(var r="",n=u,t=-1;;){if(":"===f)return r?t>=0&&t!==r.length&&(u=n+t,a("Found whitespace in your key name (use quotes to include)")):a("Found ':' but no key name (for an empty key name use quotes)"),r;" ">=f?f?0>t&&(t=r.length):a("Found EOF while looking for a key name (check your syntax)"):e(f)?a("Found '"+f+"' where a key name was expected (check your syntax or use quotes if the key name includes {}[],: or whitespace)"):r+=f,c()}},d=function(){for(;f;){for(;f&&" ">=f;)c();if("#"===f||"/"===f&&"/"===s(0))for(;f&&"\n"!==f;)c();else{if("/"!==f||"*"!==s(0))break;for(c(),c();f&&("*"!==f||"/"!==s(0));)c();f&&(c(),c())}}},y=function(){var r=f;for(e(f)&&a("Found a punctuator character '"+f+"' when excpecting a quoteless string (check your syntax)");;){if(c(),3===r.length&&"'''"===r)return p();var t="\r"===f||"\n"===f||""===f;if(t||","===f||"}"===f||"]"===f||"#"===f||"/"===f&&("/"===s(0)||"*"===s(0))){var u=r[0];switch(u){case"f":if("false"===r.trim())return!1;break;case"n":if("null"===r.trim())return null;break;case"t":if("true"===r.trim())return!0;break;default:if("-"===u||u>="0"&&"9">=u){var o=n(r);if(void 0!==o)return o}}if(t)return r.trim()}r+=f}},b=function(r){var e;for(r--,e=u-2;e>r&&t[e]<=" "&&"\n"!==t[e];e--);"\n"===t[e]&&e--,"\r"===t[e]&&e--;var n=t.substr(r,e-r+1);for(e=0;e<n.length;e++)if(n[e]>" ")return n;return""},g=function(){var r,e,n=[];if(o&&(Object.defineProperty&&Object.defineProperty(n,"__WSC__",{enumerable:!1,writable:!0}),n.__WSC__=r=[]),c(),e=u,d(),r&&r.push(b(e)),"]"===f)return c(),n;for(;f;){if(n.push(x()),e=u,d(),","===f&&(c(),e=u,d()),r&&r.push(b(e)),"]"===f)return c(),n;d()}a("End of input while parsing an array (did you forget a closing ']'?)")},v=function(r){function e(r){t.c[r]=b(i),r&&t.o.push(r)}var n,t,i,s={};if(o&&(Object.defineProperty&&Object.defineProperty(s,"__WSC__",{enumerable:!1,writable:!0}),s.__WSC__=t={c:{},o:[]},r&&(t.noRootBraces=!0)),r?i=1:(c(),i=u),d(),t&&e(""),"}"===f&&!r)return c(),s;for(;f;){if(n=h(),d(),c(":"),s[n]=x(),i=u,d(),","===f&&(c(),i=u,d()),t&&e(n),"}"===f&&!r)return c(),s;d()}return r?s:void a("End of input while parsing an object (did you forget a closing '}'?)")},x=function(){switch(d(),f){case"{":return v();case"[":return g();case'"':return l();default:return y()}},m=function(){switch(d(),f){case"{":return v();case"[":return g()}try{return v(!0)}catch(e){r();try{return x()}catch(n){throw e}}};return function(e,n){var u;return o=n&&n.keepWsc,t=e,r(),u=m(),d(),f&&a("Syntax error, found trailing characters"),u}}(),u=function(){function t(r){return" ">=r}function u(r){return r.replace(d,function(r){var e=v[r];return"string"==typeof e?e:"\\u"+("0000"+r.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})}function f(r,e,f,i){if(!r)return'""';y.lastIndex=0,g.lastIndex=0;var a=p||f||y.test(r),c=r[0],s=r[r.length-1];return a||t(c)||'"'===c||"'"===c&&"'"===r[1]&&"'"===r[2]||"#"===c||"/"===c&&("*"===r[1]||"/"===r[1])||"{"===c||"["===c||t(s)||void 0!==n(r,!0)||g.test(r)?(d.lastIndex=0,b.lastIndex=0,d.test(r)?b.test(r)||i?'"'+u(r)+'"':o(r,e):'"'+r+'"'):r}function o(r,e){var n,t=r.replace(/\r/g,"").split("\n");if(e+=k,1===t.length)return"'''"+t[0]+"'''";var u=c+e+"'''";for(n=0;n<t.length;n++)u+=c,t[n]&&(u+=e+t[n]);return u+c+e+"'''"}function i(r){return r?x.test(r)?(d.lastIndex=0,'"'+(d.test(r)?u(r):r)+'"'):r:'""'}function a(r,e,n,t){function u(r){return r&&"\n"===r["\r"===r[0]?1:0]}function o(r){return r&&!u(r)}function p(r){if(!r)return"";for(var e=0;e<r.length;e++){var n=r[e];if("\n"===n||"#"===n||"/"===n&&("/"===r[e+1]||"*"===r[e+1]))break;if(n>" ")return" # "+r}return r}switch(typeof r){case"string":return f(r,m,e,t);case"number":return isFinite(r)?String(r):"null";case"boolean":return String(r);case"object":if(!r)return"null";var d,y;s&&(d=r.__WSC__);var b="[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.apply(r),g=b||!t||(d?!d.noRootBraces:h),v=m;g&&(m+=k);var x,j,w,_,O=c+v,S=c+m,E=n||l?"":O,F=[];if(b){for(x=0,j=r.length;j>x;x++)d&&F.push(p(d[x])+S),F.push(a(r[x],d?o(d[x+1]):!1,!0)||"null");d&&F.push(p(d[x])+O),_=d?E+"["+F.join("")+"]":0===F.length?"[]":E+"["+S+F.join(S)+O+"]"}else{if(d){y=p(d.c[""]);var W=d.o.slice();for(w in r)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,w)&&W.indexOf(w)<0&&W.push(w);for(x=0,j=W.length;j>x;x++)w=W[x],(g||x>0||y)&&F.push(y+S),y=p(d.c[w]),_=a(r[w],o(y)),_&&F.push(i(w)+(u(_)?":":": ")+_);(g||y)&&F.push(y+O)}else for(w in r)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,w)&&(_=a(r[w]),_&&F.push(i(w)+(u(_)?":":": ")+_));_=0===F.length?"{}":g?d?E+"{"+F.join("")+"}":E+"{"+S+F.join(S)+O+"}":F.join(d?"":S)}return m=v,_}}var c,s,l,p,h,d=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,y=/[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,b=/'''|[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,g=/^(true|false|null)\s*((,|\]|\}|#|\/\/|\/\*).*)?$/,v={"\b":"\\b"," ":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},x=/[,\{\[\}\]\s:#"]|\/\/|\/\*|'''/,m="",k="  ";return function(n,t){var u,f;if(c=r,k="  ",s=!1,l=e,h=!0,p=!1,t&&"object"==typeof t&&(("\n"===t.eol||"\r\n"===t.eol)&&(c=t.eol),f=t.space,s=t.keepWsc,l=t.bracesSameLine||e,h=t.emitRootBraces,p="always"===t.quotes),"number"==typeof f)for(k="",u=0;f>u;u++)k+=" ";else"string"==typeof f&&(k=f);return a(n,null,!0,!0)}}();return{parse:t,stringify:u,endOfLine:function(){return r},setEndOfLine:function(e){("\n"===e||"\r\n"===e)&&(r=e)},bracesSameLine:function(){return e},setBracesSameLine:function(r){e=r},rt:{parse:function(r,e){return(e=e||{}).keepWsc=!0,t(r,e)},stringify:function(r,e){return(e=e||{}).keepWsc=!0,u(r,e)}}}}();if("object"==typeof module){if("function"==typeof require){var os=require("os");Hjson.setEndOfLine(os.EOL)}module.exports=Hjson}


function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

ready(function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('convert');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // When we click out button, convert the "bad" json into actual json
    var hjson_text = document.querySelector('.hjson').value;
    
    var converted_text = Hjson.parse(hjson_text);
    
    document.querySelector('.json').value = JSON.stringify(converted_text, null, '  ');
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" class="hjson" id="hjson">
  {
    'dontWorry': 123,
    "about a thing": 4,
    becauseEverything: [6,5,4]
    WillBeAlright: {a:1},
  }
</textarea>
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" class="json" readonly></textarea>

<div><button id="convert">
Convert HJSON to JSON
</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would need that, but `jQuery.parseJSON()` seems to be able to parse malformed JSON object. An alternative solution would be to use `dirty-json` module on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-json

Could you please provide more information on why exactly you'd need this to happen, as it might be something else that could be improved upon.

Comment: Note on https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-json - it is AGPL, so any code linked to it will need open sourced as well. In that regard, it is not a free library (has restrictions and costs your source code)

Answer (score 1):

**The cross target JSON parser in the Haxe standard library conforms to the JSON specifications.**

The json you want to use is NOT valid json so it is not supported by Haxe's standard parser, since the purpose of Haxe is to build robust and error free projects. If you need to deal with broken data it's normally your responsibility to make the call of how you handle that by writting your own parser or fixing the faulty data. Haxe provides plenty of tools to do whatever you need, but the Haxe Foundation avoid implement standards wrongly.
The Haxe compiler can often help you know if your data is broken and using macros you can load or inline check XML or JSON data at compile.

Documentation on JSON parsing structures.
   http://haxe.org/manual/std-Json-parsing.html

**TJSON - for using broken JSON within Haxe**

But for "broken" JSON, there seems to be a library that already exists.

https://github.com/martamius/TJSON

```
var jsonData = "{key:'value'}";
var object = TJSON.parse(jsonData);
trace(object.key); // outputs 'value'
```

So I would suggest you try using that, but there are many tools to validate and check your JSON, perhaps it's a much better approach to stick to the JSON spec as it will no doubt provide more predictablity, and will be more reliable and probably parse faster.

But if you have no control over the JSON data and have any problems with using TJSON please let us know I am sure Haxe is a good approach.